# Blur effect on single lens image in Quest 2 VR application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

i need to create an app for Amblyopia (Lazy Eye) treatment in Unity for Meta Quest 2 VR.
Is there a way to apply the blur effect on the chosen weak eye only?

Is it something that i need to configure through Unity IDE or do i need to create a script or elsemore it's related to Meta Quest hardware? I've tried to search in the web but there isn't so much about the cited problem.